# Can only men pass on the will of D.?

Tags: one-piece

So I was wondering how the will of D. is passed on. We have seen three cases where the will of D. was shown to be passed on and they were all from generation to generation by birth. Luffy got it from Dragon, Dragon got it from Garp and Ace got it from Roger (and Rouge?). In each case the will was passed on along with the last name. Now this made me wonder. Is it merely in a name? Or is there more to it?

Ace would probably be the best example. He chose to go through life using his mother's name *Portgas D.* Now what if Ace's mother would not have been a carrier, would Ace have not have had the will of D because of his name? Or what if Ace's mother married some other guy who didn't have the will of D, would she be unable to pass it on, because children are given their fathers name? This sounds pretty sexist to me, so it made me wonder whether just having the right surname is enough for someone to have the will of D or if there is some other way to become a D or to pass on the will of D?

If there isn't, the will of D will probably die out pretty soon...

Comment: the will of d isn't bound to the name itself. They have it in the blood, So Ace could have named himself how ever he wants and still whould have the will of D.

Comment: @Mintri So how would we know if he had the will of D and whether he would be giving it along, if he was called Ace Doe for example, if rouge had married mister Doe? According to that theory there could be many more D's we just dont know about.

Comment: nobody know what actually will of D mean, only thing explained are that they can dominate God. Almost all part of D is mystery and will be raveled in coming chapter till then it will be hard to say anything related to D, meaning , passing , history .

Comment: @PeterRaeves yes thats the point. I believe that somehow the blood of every D person is connected. that in that blood lies a hidden power. maybe dragon or garp does know somethign about that or vegapunk or it's written on a super hidden porneglyph. But imo to believe that the D alaone in a name gives any power is a bit too dull compared to the story twists in one piece :D

Answer (score 1):

OK, this is a hard question and not much is released about it till now.

Here's a short summary:

There are multiple characters in the One Piece universe with the letter D in their name:

**Monkey D. Luffy, Monkey D. Garp, Monkey D. Dragon, Gol D. Roger, Trafalgar D. Water Law, Marshall D. Teach, Portgas D. Rouge** and more.

In the [Wiki](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Will_of_the_D.), I found this:

> Whitebeard noted that killing the bloodline of a D does not put out the flames that they (a person carrying the "D") carry and someone else simply will pick it up one day

So there, the "D" is linked to someone's name and not to the bloodline itself. So this would mean, you can't wipe out the will of "D". It will appear somewhere else in some other family.

Law said:

> What's the Dark King thinking this time? The Will of the D. will almost certainly call up a storm again

and also the [Gorosei](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Gorosei) mentions:

> "D" means danger

So we can say this question is not surely answerable right now. But I'm quite sure this "D" is not just about bloodline. I agree that in the Monkey family the will is given to the next generation, but I don't think it's just about the blood, it's more than that.

***Update***: I also found a pretty interesting where "the will of D" could mean "the will to die". [Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/OnePiece/comments/2mpnj8/will_of_d_theory/)

> Gol D. Roger, gave himself in the arms of death to inspire a new generation of pirates. Portgas D. Ace, fought for the honor of his captain and died saving his brother.
>   Let's take a look at Marshall D. Teach. While fighting with Whitebeard he showed clear signs that he feared death. Minutes later we get a speech from Whitebeard telling us that he was not the man Roger is waiting for, and that he was also not a true D.*

You can find this in chapter 576.

[image: Chapter 576 Page 8]
[image: Chapter 576 Page 11]

*At this point, Whitebeard speaks also about the "bloodline" and not just about the name. And you also never know how correctly translated this mangas are.
I know its not a clear answer, but maybe you found some aspects which helps you.*